# Grid и координаты

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

Есть ли у Grid, какие нибудь удобные средства, что бы можно было легко проверить, какой клеточки таблицы пренадолжать координаты x y?
Т.е. у меня есть координаты x y от клика мышкой, и мне нужно определить по какой клетке Grid кликнул пользователь... Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли Grid, или его колонок, или столбцов, какой нибудь специальный метод для этого?

Comment: А зачем вам? Пусть лучше содержимое клетки само подпишется на клик, и адекватно реагирует.

Comment: Ну там небольшая игрушка будет. И нужно отслеживать положение героя в игровом пространстве(которое представляет из себя Grid ), нужно будет проверять в какой клетке он окажется. Вот я и подумал, может Grida есть какой нибудь метод, которые опредлял бы какой клетке принадлежат координаты.

Comment: Если по клику, то почитай в MSDN про событие PreviewMouseDown. Можешь еще запросить у гугла по ключевым словам "WPF grid cell mouse click", масса решений даже на 1 странице.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: ну, пускай клетки на клик и реагируют, что мешает так сделать?